# I am trying to download stop words from nltk and NLTK Downloader shows WinError 10060 (Error connecting to server) and says connection attempt failed

Tags: python-3.x, windows, nlp, nltk, stop-words

I am typing the following in both jupyter notebook and cmd(Adminstrator mode):
`import nltk nltk.download()`

Both give the same result, which is this:

[image: This dialog box shows up when I run nltk.download() and the NLTK Downloader also shows up]

[image: The downloader shows empty. I don't understand why this is happening]

Next when I clock OK on the dialog box, the NLTK downloader goes to Not Responding.

The same WinError 10060 comes when I try nltk.download('all) or even nltk.download('punkt).

Can somebody please explain why this is happening and what do I have to do for downloading NLTK Stopwords?

Comment: It seems a network issue. try running pip install and let me know

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same error and I tried numerous ways and wasted lot of days. After that I tried this again by switching my network. I was using WIFI before then I tried with Mobile hotspot and it worked. So please try switching the network and check.